# How to parser the json object dynamically in logstsh using ruby code

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-grok

I have this as input, I need to parse all the keys and values and put in a separate event, can you please help me how to achieve, Actually I'm only one key and value when I using the below ruby code.

```
"entities": {
"PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-EA653E6874E21338": "WebSphere AS nzapwa145Cell (nzapwa146 / ePIMS_pwa146)",
"PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-64A2967FB7FC0C5B": "WebSphere AS ndmProd (nzapwa127 / ePIMS_Report_pwa127)",
"PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-4738C9392BDBC296": "EPS Store - 900008014",
"PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-BA196B9B53FF6323": "EPS Store - 900008040",
"PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-D5D2DAB06C8FDAAF": "ws-server.jar prod-sj-userprofile-adapter-service- - -*",
"PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-3EABAD79933CE911": "/apps/conf/httpd-p2_cdis.conf - KPATHS",
}
```

Code:

```
ruby {
code => '
event.get("[result][entities]").each { |key, value|
event.set("hostId", key)
event.set("serverName", value)
}
'
}
```

Output for above code:

```
{"serverName":"/apps/conf/httpd-p2_cdis.conf - KPATHS)","@timestamp":"2018-08-25T15:17:11.762Z","hostId":"PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-3EABAD79933CE911"}
```

But desired output will be like this :

```
{"serverName":"WebSphere AS nzapwa145Cell (nzapwa146 / ePIMS_pwa146)","@timestamp":"2018-08-25T15:17:11.762Z","hostId":"PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-EA653E6874E21338"}
{"serverName":"WebSphere AS ndmProd (nzapwa127 / ePIMS_Report_pwa127)","@timestamp":"2018-08-25T15:17:11.762Z","hostId":"PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-64A2967FB7FC0C5B"}
{"serverName":"EPS Store - 900008014","@timestamp":"2018-08-25T15:17:11.762Z","hostId":"PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-4738C9392BDBC296"}
{"serverName":"ws-server.jar prod-sj-userprofile-adapter-service- - -*","@timestamp":"2018-08-25T15:17:11.762Z","hostId":"PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-BA196B9B53FF6323"}
{"serverName":"/apps/conf/httpd-p2_cdis.conf - KPATHS","@timestamp":"2018-08-25T15:17:11.762Z","hostId":"PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-D5D2DAB06C8FDAAF"}
{"serverName":"/apps/conf/httpd-p2_cdis.conf - KPATHS)","@timestamp":"2018-08-25T15:17:11.762Z","hostId":"PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-3EABAD79933CE911"}
```

Can you please help me to get the solution, I'm facing problem with ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Logstash expert, but I think your Ruby filter overwrites (sets) the value `hostId` and `serverName` multiple times while iterating over all given key-value pairs. That leaves you with the values that were set in the last iteration. After all, there is only one event, so your keys need to be unique. To fix that, you need to extend your event's key field by either nesting it in tree structure or creating unique key strings.

Here, `hostId` is the unique key :

```
ruby {
code => '
event.get("[result][entities]").each do |key, value|
  event.set(key, value)
end
'
}
```

Here an additional index is added to ensure unique keys:

```
ruby {
code => '
idx = 0
event.get("[result][entities]").each do |key, value|
  event.set("[#{idx}][hostId]", key)
  event.set("[#{idx}][serverName]", value)
  idx += 1
end
'
}
```

I hope you find that helpful.